Selecting * and a column by name creates an ambiguous column error in SQL Server
SQL Server: let's say I have a table with Column1 and Column2.
Why does this:
SELECT Column1, * 
FROM MyTable 
ORDER BY Column1;

throw an error:

Ambiguous column name 'Column1'

but this:
SELECT Column1, * 
FROM MyTable 
ORDER BY MyTable.Column1;

does NOT throw an error?
Tried running both commands

Did you look at the columns returned from the query that works?

Your SELECT has two columns called Column1 and you are asking SQL Server to order by it, but it doesn't know which. The first one, or the second one? Using the prefix tells it to use the value from the table's column.

SELECT Column1, * FROM MyTable ORDER BY Column1;

is effectively
SELECT Column1, Column1, Column2 FROM MyTable ORDER BY Column1;

thus engine gets confused and doesn't know which Column1 to use for sorting.

On the other hand by writing the query like
SELECT Column1, * FROM MyTable ORDER BY MyTable.Column1;

it will be sorting by Column1, but it know you mean specific Column1 name from specific table. Imagine, you have two tables you are joining and both have column with Column1 name. Engine can't decide which Column1 from which table you mean. In your case it is pretty obvious those are same, but in other use cases it is not, thus the error.
If you don't like to use table name, you can use different name for column.
SELECT Column1 as c1, * FROM MyTable ORDER BY c1;


